# ubuntu 12.04 system running so slow after installing xen and changing grub settings

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, xen

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 system where I just installed XEN using these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed

I set the memory limit to be 512M. 
Now.. when I reboot the computer, it is so slow, it's taken 10 minutes to render the default desktop (kate) after I log in. 
I'm not savvy enough with Linux to know how to undo this properly. If I wanted to test undoing the changes to grub, what would be the reverse of this command?

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=.*\+/GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"/' /etc/default/grub
```

If you have any other suggestions on how I can resolve this, that'd be great. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the following value in /etc/default/grub:

```
 GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```